# Filter object list by latest datetime with single orderId in lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have `Queryable` of object

`IQueryable<Orders> orders = Repository.GetOrders();`

I have now a list of Orders with some common `orderId` and i need to fetch only unique `orderIds` with latest `date` in queryable of objects

`Queryable<Orders> ordersWithLatestDate = orders.Where(?)` <= (Need Lambda query here)

Answer (score 0):

You can group the orders by `Id` and then project each group on the date column :

```
var ordersWithLatestDate = orders.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                            .Select( g => new 
                                { 
                                    Orderid = g.Key, 
                                    OrderDateTime = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDateTime)
                                                     .Select(y => y.OrderDateTime)
                                                     .First()
                                });
```

### EDIT:

This will work with IQuerable as well:

```
var ordersWithLatestDate = orders.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                        .Select( g => 
                                g.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDateTime)
                                                 .Select(y => y.OrderDateTime)
                                                 .First()
                               );
```

Comment: This one i used but getting exception

`Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Comment: But while i am using this code after converting `IQueryable<Orders> orders` to `.ToList()` then this lambda expression working perfectly, but in `Queryable` its coming issue

Comment: @RajsekharPatnaik we can't use anonymous object in IQueryable i guess,

Comment: @RajsekharPatnaik see the edit for the version which will work with `IQueryable`

Comment: Hi @ehsansajjad i tried this one also but not working same issue but thisone also working after converted to list